# Google Embedded Iframe Calendar Not Displaying Events Consistently

Tags: iframe, google-calendar-api

I've made up an intranet for the company I work with. The intranet requires the user to log in with their Google account to get access. As such, I've also set up an embed code for Google Calendars using the default iframe embed and used a little php to swap out the calendar to look at the user's email to show the appropriate calendar to them (ex: logging in as joe@gmail.com will populate the calendar with joe@gmail.com's address while logging in as jill@gmail.com will populate the calendar with jill@gmail.com's address).

This has worked well for most people, but there are some troubles we are running into with certain browsers and the errors are very inconsistent, which has made troubleshooting difficult. Also, when I check the source code, the correct email is showing up in the iframe so the php swapping is likely not the issue.

**Example 1:** I log in with Firefox on Windows 10. The calendar works as expected.

**Example 2:** I log in with Chrome on Windows 10. The calendar shows, but events do not display. No errors are given.

**Example 3:** Co-worker #1 logs in with Chrome on Windows 10. The calendar works as expected.

**Example 4**: Co-worker #2 logs in with Chrome on Windows 10. He gets a "You do not have permission to view one or more calendars" error despite the source code clearly pointing to only his personal calendar, which he undoubtedly has access to (He is also logged into his Google account on Google itself, so it's not a conflict there either).

**Example 5:** I log in with Chrome on Windows 10 in Incognito Mode. The calendar works as expected.

**Example 6:** I log in with Edge on Windows 10. The calendar works on the initial log in, but the moment I navigate to another page, the calendar still displays but all events disappear with no errors displayed. This persists until I log in again.

**Example 7:** Co-worker #3 logs in with Chrome on Mac OSX. The calendar works on the initial log in, but the moment she navigates to another page, the calendar still displays but all events disappear with no errors displayed. This persists until she logs in again. (This is consistent across any browser she uses)

**Example 8:** Co-worker #4 logs in with Chrome on Mac OSX. The calendar works as expected.

Ultimately I'm just lost on where to start with searching for these errors and narrowing down what the cause is. Clearing caches only seems to work sometimes, and other times even causes a different error to start popping up. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing these inconsistent errors and where to start looking for fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is still an [intermitttent issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/-AbGDUQdA_A) when using embedded Iframe calendar with a different browser.

Here are some suggested solutions for this issue:

- Clearing the cache and cookies
- Before integrating the calendar, click the ***Customize*** button from the Google Calendar Settings on [how to embed on your website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en) then try to explore.
- From this [github post](https://github.com/nextcloud/calendar/issues/169), rullzer suggest an idea of a cleaner approach to handle cookies on IFRAME to migrate to lax samesite cookies for all cookies.

  > This only makes the cookies more secure. Plus it makes sure that if
  >   you embed some public page somewhere everbody will see the exact same
  >   thing. (as the IFRAME won't send any cookies then resulting in a true
  >   'publicpage' rendering).

Comment: Thanks Jess! Unfortunate to hear that this has been a problem for years that hasn't fully been fixed. I did try looking at that github post you tried to link to, but I think you copied the wrong link as it just takes me to the "how to embed on your website" link.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed the link :)